# preg_replace modify text and save to database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

Recently i [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209205/preg-match-find-and-replace-a-string-pattern)  which was used to replace iframes in database with shortcode. It did work for some contents but for some others it caused inconsistancy resulting a string like

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106645167" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>"]
```

This should be

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106645167"]
```

I think this has been caused due to different iframes in database. I need to know that if there is any other way by which i can fix the issue on my database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, now you want to convert the *wrong* output

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106645167" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>"]
```

to the *right* outut?

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106645167"]
```

#### Regex

If so (and assuming that all instances are the same format: i.e. url first) then the following will work:

```
preg_replace('/(\[soundcloud url=".*?").*?(\])/', '$1$2', $string);
```

#### Simple explanation

The above regex matches

```
[soundcloud url="all characters before" all characters before]
```

and replaces it with

```
[soundcloud url="all chracters before"]
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, That works and i have some other problem now. can we make `[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/8970784" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="450"&gt;` to `[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/8970784"]`