# Search for iframe replace with shortcode

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, preg-replace, soundcloud

I am trying to convert all the iframes from database to wordpress shortcode. Here is a sample string

```
<iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F59701079&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>came over from Berlin for a couple of days. Mad fun that guy is!! We actually made 2 tracks during his stay here. The other one will be released soon.<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z3fIsvQDrqI" frameborder="0" width="460" height="259"></iframe>\r\n<strong><span style="color: #3366ff;">GDD:</span></strong> So wild! Well we''re very happy you''re getting the deserved attention! Tell us what you have coming up next in the Kill Frenzy world!\r\n<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>KF:</strong></span><iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F53146049&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>
```

Basically what i am trying to do is to convert the

`<iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F59701079&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>`

to

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/59701079"]
```

So ultimately the string will be converted to something like this

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/59701079"] came over from Berlin for a couple of days. Mad fun that guy is!! We actually made 2 tracks during his stay here. The other one will be released soon.<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z3fIsvQDrqI" frameborder="0" width="460" height="259"></iframe>\r\n<strong><span style="color: #3366ff;">GDD:</span></strong> So wild! Well we''re very happy you''re getting the deserved attention! Tell us what you have coming up next in the Kill Frenzy world!\r\n<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>KF:</strong></span>[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/5314604"]
```

Actually i had already asked the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209205/preg-match-find-and-replace-a-string-pattern)

It works when there is only one iframe in the string. When there is more than one iframe then it is showing some odd results. And when there are other iframes like youtube,vimeo then also it is showing problem. I wasted around 10 hours but couldn't find a solution. So if any expert can help me in getting this done then i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't use regexes on html. use dom to find the iframes, and replace them with a textnode containing your shortcode.

Comment: Yes, but i am not able to figure out how exactly i can achieve this. This will be just one time code.

Answer (score 0):

To tell the difference between soundcloud iframes and other iframes you can set as "search keyword" "Search and Replace to find all instances and replace them with whatever you want.

Similarly, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605768/search-and-replace-part-of-string-in-database). It is not for wordpress specifically, but you can see how it handles the find and replace in the mysql databases.

Comment: Thanks but this is not just replacing, its about first get the value and then do a replacement.